# How to write single function for search in row wise and column wise sorted 2d array(limit is function should be like int search(int *A,int n,int key))

Tags: c, sorting, search

Hello guys I wrote a programm to generate random numbers and then sort those numbers row wise and column wise and at the end the function search to find key inside the 2d array but today my proff said you should send me just single function like this int search(int *A,int n,int key) so that  I can test it in my program I have no idea how to do it the limits are columns and rows are between 2-5000 and elements are between 0 till int Max and problem said test if n is increasing and suppose matrix is n by n and every rows and column are sorted.

My previous program was this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define R 5000
#define C 5000

int arr[R][C];
int search(int arr[][C], int r, int c, int key) {
    if(key < arr[0][0] || key > arr[r - 1][c - 1])
        return -1;
    r = 0;
    c = c - 1;
    while(r <= c - 1 && c >= 0) {
        if(arr[r][c] < key)
            r++;
        else if(arr[r][c] > key)
            c--;
        else
            return 1;
    }
}

void sort_rows(int *arr, int n)
{
    int i;
    for(i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        int key = arr[i];
        int j = i - 1;
        while(j >= 0 && key < arr[j])
        {
            arr[j + 1] = arr[j];
            j--;
        }
        arr[j + 1] = key;
    }
}
void sort_column(int arr[][C], int r, int c)
{
    int key, k;
    int i, j;
    for(i = 0; i < r; i++)
    {
        for(j = 1; j < c; j++)
        {
            key = arr[j][i];
            k = j - 1;
            while(k >= 0 && arr[k][i] > key)
            {
                arr[k + 1][i] = arr[k][i];
                k--;
            }
            arr[k + 1][i] = key;
        }
    }
}
int main()
{
    int r, c;
    int key;
    int i, j, size_row, size_column;
    printf("Enter Number of rows and columns(2-%d,2-%d):", R, C);
    scanf("%d%d", &r, &c);
    for(i = 0; i < r; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < c; j++)
            arr[i][j] = rand() % (r * c) + 1;
    }
    printf("Original array:\n");
    for(i = 0; i < r; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < c; j++)
        {
            printf("%d ", arr[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    for(i = 0; i < r; i++)
    {
        sort_rows(arr[i], c);
    }
    sort_column(arr, r, c);
    printf("Sorted Array:\n");
    for(i = 0; i < r; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < c; j++)
        {
            printf("%d ", arr[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    printf("Enter element to search:");
    scanf("%d", &key);
    if(search(arr, r, c, key) == -1) printf("the %d not found", key);
    else  printf("the %d  is found", key);
}
```

So I dont know how to implement like that 
any help would be great thank you so much

Comment: You missed a `return 0;` or similar at the end of your `search` function.

Comment: Thanks for mention about it but problem is I want to implement search function such that my proff can use it inside his program my search function should be called like the form that i wrote int search(int *A,int n,int key)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the that int* arr is cast from a 2D array, contiguously allocated, and that the functions signature is:

> int search(int *arr,int n,int key))

```
if(key < arr[0] || key > arr[n*n-1])
    return -1;
r = 0;
c = n - 1;
while(r <= c - 1 && c >= 0) {
    if(arr[r*n+c] < key)
        r++;
    else if(arr[r*n+c] > key)
        c--;
    else
        return 1;
}
return -1;
```

This should work, assuming the array is square (number of columns equals number of rows), this function will return -1 if element is not found and 1 if it is found.

Comment: Thank you so much I have a question does it make sense test if n is increasing actually my professor said this function should be tested in his program on sorted column and row-wise n by n 2d array

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question very well, what do you mean by "does it make sense test if n is increasing" ?

Comment: I mean test if that array is  passed is row sort and column sort in increasing way

Comment: If your professor said that the input will be sorted, you don't have to check if it's sorted or not.

Comment: thanks for your great respond but how can i implement this function exactly with int *arr not int **arr if i do so should i change something it will be really amazing if you can solve this problem for me I have time until this night but I don't know how to work with this pointer and change pointer to pointer in the form of just int search(int *arr,int n,int key) cause he said to me it should be like that not **arr and there is way to do it

Comment: It should be something like int search(int[][n])arr,int n,int key) should I change anything inside my function or still the same sorry for bothering its really important to me and my I am the first year with little c background

Comment: I don't think so, you can try it first

Comment: Actually the problem is i dont know how he did his program to just put my function there and see if it is work. inside of my program for example I passed r , c but there is no r  and c passing in function int search(int *arr,int n,int key) so I can t see if it is work or not

Comment: no need for both r and c since it's a given that it's r and c are equal n, if I assume that int* arr is simply cast from a 2D array, you can keep the int* arr and change how you access it, so instead of using arr[i][j] you use arr[i*n+j], this approach works only if the 2D array is allocated contguously

Comment: ok thank you so much exactly my professor wanted this but i don't how would you please just modify the access part I m really stuck I did lot of things but it did not work

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and your help this is really amazing that there is person like you that put time for other people like me thank you so much there is lots of time that I wanna get quite from my major but still there are people out there that help the others

Comment: again thank you so much for your help but I passed the function to my prof and he tested the function and it did not worked it compiled well but it did not work I have just 3 hour to fix it so again thank you for helping me

Answer (score 0):

```
int search(int *arr,int n,int key) {

if(key < arr[0] || key > arr[n*n-1])
return 0;
int r = 0;
int c = n - 1;
while(r <= c - 1 && c >= 0) {
    if(arr[r*n+c] < key)
        r++;
    else if(arr[r*n+c] > key)
        c--;
    else
        return 1;
}
return 0;
}
```

I changed -1 with zero just because limit of  the programm and just declare r and c and nothing else but it did not work there was not compilation failed it is problem inside of programm so would you please tell me what could it be wrong

Comment: use the program you posted the first time and replace the function with the  new one, and change how you call it to "search((int*)arr, r, key)" and test it

Comment: no this does not work I m trying to declare new array row wise and column wise sorted for example an[n][n] ={ ........} then passing it to the function cause if i want to use my programm everything going to be change the function compiled well so it means something inside it has a problem no_